Why is נַעֲרָה spelled without a ה?
In almost every instance in the Torah, the word נַעֲרָה is spelled without a ה at the end. Do any commentaries suggest any reasons for this, specifically how it relates to Rivkah?

Is it ever spelled with a final hei?

@DoubleAA Deut 22:19, and then regularly in Nakh.

@magicker seems like any connection to chayei sara / rivka is misplaced

Somewhere in kesubos it says that whenever naara is spelled without a hey it means to include girls that are younger than 12 as well, but that's presumably referencing specifically where that would be halachically significant

@Loani interesting, so here to allude maybe that Rivkah was less than 12 perhaps?

The word נער probably wasn’t inflected for gender until the times of the נביאים, at which point the new feminine inflection was imposed into the Torah’s text.

The commentary Minchas Shai extensively deals with the problem. Minchas Shai on Bereshis 34:3 says:

את הנער. לב הנער. הנערה ק' וכן השני והשלישי ובמסורת כל אורייתא חסר במ"א וענשו אותו מאה דפ' כי תצא וכמ"ש שם והה"א לבדה במאריך וכן כולם במדוייקים:
Young Girl. Heart of a Young Girl. The full spelling נַעֲרָה can be found 100 times (in Tanach). But incomplete spelling ָנַעֲר, which we also see here in the second and third cases, is found 41 times (in Tanakh), and the one out of the 100 full spellings is penalized in parashas Ki Tetze where we explained that it is an exceptional case. All of these spellings are verified.

Minchas Shai on Bereshis 24:14  refers to Zohar "daf 51", according to Sefaria, Zohar perek 86, which says:

When they had returned, Rabbi Simeon spoke: The description I have given may be taken as a symbol of the holy unity of God. In the holy name YHVH, the second letter hé is the blue or black light attached to the remaining letters yod, hé, vav, which constitute the luminous white light.
But there come times when this blue light is not héi (ה) but dalet (ד), which is to say, poverty; this means, when Israel fail to cleave to it from beneath and it in turn fails therefore to burn and cleave to the white light, the blue light is dalet (ד), but when Israel make it to cleave to the white light, then it is hei (ה).
מְנָלָן דִּכְתִיב, (דברים כ״ב:כ״ג) כִּי יִהְיֶה נַעֲרָה בְּתוּלָה, נַעַר כְּתִיב בְּלָא ה'. מַאי טַעְמָא בְּגִין דְּלָא אִתְחַבְּרַת בִּדְכוּרָא. וּבְכָל אֲתַר דְּלָא אִשְׁתַּכְּחוּ דְּכַר וְנוּקְבָא, ה"א לָא אִשְׁתְּכַח וְסָלְקָא מִתַּמָּן וְאִשְׁתָּאַר ד'.
Why is it written in Devarim 22:23 "When there is a young (נַעֲרָה) virgin ..." but in other cases ָנַעַר without ה? What is the reason? On account that she would not join with the male. And in every place that we would not find both male and female, the letter ה will not be found, and therefore there remains only letter ד.

The fact that Rivka was 14 and over the age of 12 can be learned from the analysis of the Midrash Seder Olam Oriental manuscripts although European manuscripts state that she was 3. In other words, Zohar hints that Rivka did not develop fully and could not have children.

Finally, to address the point in parashas Ki Teitze, Devarim 22:19:

ונתנו לאבי הנערה. לית מלא בתורה והכי נמי אמרינן בכתובות פרק ג' ופרק ד' אמר ר"ל המוציא שם רע על הקטנה פטור שנאמר ונתנו לאבי הנערה נערה מלא דבר הכתוב וכו' ולפיכך יש לתמוה על הרמב"ם ז"ל והקרית ספר דבריש פרק ג' מהלכות נערה בתולה כתבו ואינו חייב עד שיוציא על הנערה שנאמ' והוציאו את בתולי הנערה נערה מלא דבר הכתוב וגם הסמ"ג בעשין נ"ה כתב כן וזה שלא בדקדוק וכבר העיר בזה הכסף משנה. ונתעוררו חז"ל בספר הזוהר על מה שכתוב בכל הפרשה נער חסר ה"א והטעם כי הה"א רומזת לה"א אחרונה של שם והיא חסרה מן הנערה הזאת אך ונתנו לאבי הנערה מלא כי היא בשלימותה וזהו כי הוציא שם רע על בתולת ישראל ורמז לכנסת ישראל של מעלה. תבין מכאן עונש המוציא שם רע עד היכן מגיע קלקולו. ריקנאטי ועיין עוד בזוהר דפוס קרימונה פרשת בראשית עמוד ס"ז:
It should not be complete in the Torah, and so it is said in Gemara Kesubos perek 3 and 4, for example Kesubos 40b
Reish Lakish said: One who slanders a minor girl, falsely claiming that she was not a virgin on the wedding night, is exempt from paying the fine, as it is stated: “And they shall give them to the father of the young woman [נַעֲרָה]” (Deuteronomy 22:19). The verse spoke of נַעֲרָה, not only pronounced but written in full, indicating that this payment is in effect only with regard to a young woman, not a minor girl. However, in places where the term is written נַעֲרָ, even a minor girl would be included.
Therefore, one can wonder on the words of Rambam and Kiryas Sefer, an in the beginning perek 3, hilkhos Virgin Maiden (Naarah Besula) where they wrote:
He is not liable unless he issues a slanderous report regarding a na'arah. (1)(2) [This is derived from Deuteronomy 22:15]: "[They will] present signs of the maiden's virginity." The word נערה, "maiden" is written in a full form. (3)(4)
And also SM"G B'Osin 55 wrote so, which is not according to grammar. And already Kesef Mishneh arose awareness about it. And in Sefer haZohar they aroused attention when in the entire parasha used נַעֲרָ (without ה) and the reason  that the letter hei (ה) hints to the final ה of the name and it is lacking from this (particular) maiden. However, in this case ונתנו לאבי הנערה it is spelled with hei (ה) because she is a mature virgin (b'sheleimusa), and that is why a man who slanders a virgin of Israel, hints to the congregarion of Israel of the above. One should understand from here the punishment of the slanderer, and how far the damage that he inflicts goes. (Rekanati and also look in Zohar, Dfus Kadmon (Old Edition?), section Bereshis Amud 67).

By the way, if one stares into the words of Zohar for a long time, one finds why Yehudah spelled with hei has good children with Tamar spelled without hei, and one should not worry about Yosef and Osnath, for ת at the end is also feminine like hei. Also Sarai did not have hei and with her husband Avram they lacked ability to have children, which explains the name their name change to Avraham and Sarah.

(1) As mentioned previously, the term na'arah implies a specific time frame: the six months after a girl's manifestation of physical signs of maturity once she has reached the age of twelve.
(2) As mentioned in the notes on Chapter 1, Halachah 8, the word na'arah, "maiden" is sometimes used by the Torah to refer to girls between the ages of three and twelve and a half. In this instance, however, the meaning of the term is specific.
(3) Generally, the word נערה, maiden, is written in the Torah without the final heh. The inclusion of the heh is obviously purposeful and intended to teach a concept.
(4) The Rambam's statements have aroused the attention of the commentaries, for in our Torah scrolls the word נערה in the verse cited by the Rambam lacks a heh. The Kessef Mishneh (based on Ketubot 40b and Rashi, 44b) notes that the Talmud derives this concept from Deuteronomy 22:19: "And he shall give it to the father of the maiden." In that verse, the word נערה is written with a heh in our Torah scrolls.

Also Rachel didn't have children initially and her name has no Heh so she gave Yakov her  maidservant Bilhah, whose name has two Hehs (I learned this from Rabbi A. Levene zts"l)
